# NULL to 0 values in vactor attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I need to converte NULL values to 0 values with the overall goal of sum up two columns in attribute table in QGIS. Since one of these colums has NULL values, the new column with the sum also appears with NULL value (instead of preserving numeric value of other column).

I have tried Selecting column by all NULL value and putting 0 in Expression Field but that does not work.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are asking. Can you attach a screen shot with an example output or anything showing clearly what you are trying to accomplish? Please edit  your original question to add more information. Also form a better question than just any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the value as `if value is None:` for your comparison?  Like do that first then sub in 0 for the value.

Comment: @Andrea The `coalesce` function of field calculator works nicely for your requeriment.

Comment: Duplicate? The objetive was to sum two columns in attribute table ignoring NULL values (so, the question was bad formulated). My solution is shorter than the another answer and it doesn't need to change NULL values in zeros previously to get the sum.

Answer (score 7):

If your problem is equivalent to this (where **test3** is the sum of **test** + **test2**):

[image]

you can solve it with the **coalesce** function (Conditionals) of field calculator of QGIS.

The sintaxis (for the sum) is in the next image (NULL values are changed by zeros):

[image]

Afterward OK, the values in **test3** (update existing field) are calculated, as espected, in the following image:

[image]