# PyQGIS: Inline function to replace NULL values with 0 in all fields (not coalesce)?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3, null

Now I know there are several ways to tackle this problem but so far none of the following worked for me.
I got a huge attribute table out of various spatial joins so pretty much all of the fields have NULL values in some rows. This table will be processed and new fields are going to be calculated programatically so [the solution involving the coalesce function](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147137/null-to-0-values-in-vactor-attribute-table-in-qgis) is out of the race because the expressions for the following calculations are complex enough and I don't want to do all that typing. So here are my failed attempts of fiddeling together a function that i can use inline:

```
def replaceNulls(layer):
   context = QgsExpressionContext()
   context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))
   with edit(layer):
      for field in layer.fields().names():
          for feat in layer.getFeatures():
              expr = QgsExpression('if({f} is null,0,{f})'.format(f=field))
              feat[field] = expr.evaluate(context)
              layer.updateFeature(feat)
```

Using an expression [from this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/304383/86042) replaces ALL the fields with 0 and some with `field` - independent of their field type.

```
def replaceNulls(layer):
   context = QgsExpressionContext()
   context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))
   with edit(layer):
      for field in layer.fields().names():
          for feat in layer.getFeatures():
              expr = QgsExpression('case when {f} is null then 0 else {f} end'.format(f=field))
              feat[field] = expr.evaluate(context)
              layer.updateFeature(feat)
```

This function replaces all values that are NOT NULL with 0 for some reason all though [it is said here](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-using-expressions-to-compute-new-field-values/) that:

> The expression syntax is exactly the same as in the field calculator GUI. So you can test them in the GIU first, before copying them into your PyQGIS script.

If that is the case what am I missing out on? The same source also mentions a more pythonic way but how to `if feat[field] is None:` when the NULL value is still a QVariant?

**TL;DR:** `replace(NULL,0)`. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So despite the very [elaborate answer by fastest](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/364055/86042) which for some reason didn't work for QVariant.Integer and QVariant.Double I ended up using a simpler solution. It might be a bit hacky but it's a classical case of "works-for-me":

```
def replace_nulls(layer):
    with edit(layer):
        for feat in layer.getFeatures():
            for field in feat.fields().names():
                if feat[field] == None:
                    feat[field] = '0'
            layer.updateFeature(feat)
```

Comment: Nice and (almost) clean. Some small improvement hints: 1. Undent `layer.updateFeature`, so it's called once per feature (not once per field). 2: Iterate `for field in feat.fields():` and check `field.isNumeric()` to decide for string vs. number.

Comment: Well apparently it seems that differenciating between datatypes is not necessary at all

Comment: It might work or not, depending on the data provider in use and other configuration details.

Comment: That's what i meant by 'classical case of works-for-me'. And as for "It might work or not, depending on the data provider in use and other luminaries": that basically applies for anything. Thanks for the flowers.

Comment: You can keep it like that or improve it as a compatible reference for future readers. It looks like this is soon going to stop working (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/36715#issue-624469015).

Comment: I did the undent but when i implement `if feat[field.name()] == None and field.isNumeric():
                feat[field.name()] = 0.0` the NULL will not be replaced by something other than a '0'. Can you replicate that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109065/discussion-between-maxwhere-and-matthias-kuhn).

Answer (score 3):

one way I found to solve the issue of replacing the `NULL` values with zeros or similar values is the following:

1. I define a function that maps the `NULL` value to some other value of choice, depending on the `QVariant` type:

```py
def map_null_to_zero(qvariant_type):
    if qvariant_type == QVariant.Invalid or qvariant_type >= QVariant.Int and qvariant_type <= QVariant.Double:
        return 0
    elif qvariant_type == QVariant.String or qvariant_type == QVariant.Char:
        return "0"
    elif qvariant_type == QVariant.Bool:
        return False
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unexpected Data type {}".format(qvariant_type))
```

2. Then, I define another function that, given an input list of attributes and attributes' types, it returns a modified list of attributes without `NULL`:

```py
def modify_null_attr_to_zero(li_attr=None, li_attr_type=None):
    assert len(li_attr) == len(li_attr_type), "The input list have different lengths"
    return [attr if attr != NULL else map_null_to_zero(type) for attr, type in zip(li_attr, li_attr_type)]
```

Note that null attributes are identified using the comparison operator (`==`) with the `NULL` type, which is a special type of the `QVariant`:

```
type(NULL)
<class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QVariant'>
```

Some more information can be found in the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#isNull).

3. Finally, I can apply the changes to the required layer:

```py
def replace_nulls(layer):
    li_attr_types = [a.type() for a in layer.fields()]
    with edit(layer):
        for f in layer.getFeatures():
            f.setAttributes(modify_null_attr_to_zero(f.attributes(), li_attr_types))
            if not layer.updateFeature(f):
                print("Error in updating feature {}".format(f.id()))
```

I think this "modular" solution gives you the flexibility of deciding how to convert `NULL` based on the type of the attribute. 
I tested it on the open dataset populated_places from the [natural earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/).
Here is how the original attribute table looks like:
[image: Excerpt of the attribute table of original layer]
And here is how it looks after the execution of the `replace_nulls` function:
[image: Excerpt of the attribute table of the modified layer]

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for your almost ready-to-use answer: it replaces QVariant.String just fine but none of the others. Interestingly if I manually add a Int or Double field with nothing in it f.attributes() shows them as pythonic None instead of NULL. The values of these field also get replaced by your script but those containing NULL are beeing ignored by layer.updateFeature(f). Why?

Comment: Hi @maxwhere, thanks for your feedback. First of all, I edited my answer by removing the ```NoGeometry``` in the feature request as this was in fact canceling the geometric information of the features. Then, it is quite interesting the behavior you describe. I have tried my script on a layer with ```NULL``` values that result from a spatial join operation and I can see that it is successful also for numeric data types. 
If the attributes in your layer successfully compare to ```NULL```, the script should work. Maybe you can check that. Cheers.

Comment: You should be able to replicate the same situation: use the first code snippet in my link to that PyQGIS 101 and replace some values with NULL or None, create a layer and pass it to the replace_nulls function of yours: Integer and Double not replaced. And yes: f[field] == NULL and f[field] == None both True.